# Anonymous `gen_server` instance?

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

Accoring to the actual docs, `gen_server:start_link` is of following signature:

> ServerName = {local,Name} | {global,GlobalName} | {via,Module,ViaName}
>   Name = atom()

..but what if I don't like to assign distinct name (neither `local` or `global`) to some `gen_server` instance and rather would like to memoize it's `PID` and reference it in such an *anonymous* fashion? Am I able to achieve such behavior?

P.S. Why do I need this? There is a parameter, let's call it `N`, which defines how many instances of the same `gen_server` is required. Current implementation does something like `instance_1`..`instance_N`, generating those atoms on the fly, but actually PIDs would be sufficient here. That's why I'd like to get rid of atoms and perefer PIDs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *ServerName* parameter is used for registration, so the server can be referenced by the name. But this parameter is optional, there exists `start_link` version without it:

```
start_link(Module, Args, Options) -> Result
start_link(ServerName, Module, Args, Options) -> Result
```

Server started by the version with three parameters is not registered. This is useful when one prefers to use other means over atoms to refer to servers, for instance when several servers of the same type are used.